# Icons not displaying with custom theme

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, icons

I'm using jQuery mobile with a custom theme created on [themeroller](http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/)
According to the instructions I have to include in the `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/mycustomtheme.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
```

My custom theme displays perfectly but if I want to use an icon like:

```
<a href="#home" data-transition="slideup" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Home</a>
```

The "home" icon doesn't show. It only displays an empty circle.

I work with google chrome.

What should I include to resolve the issue?

Comment: Code you post a link to the site or a jsfiddle?  My hunch is that the home icon is not included in your custom theme, but I cannot check without a link.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bx0UABesMdytUzU3YlZyS3ZDMXc&usp=sharing

Comment: The icon is there and is being called by the CSS, so my guess would now be that the `.ui-icon-home` class (which applies the icon png) is not being applied to the button.  Again, a live link would help us help you better.

Comment: I solved it. I didn't think I had to manually link the icons, I thought jQuery could handle it autonomously.

Comment: It should.  It is rather bizarre that it did not.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `data-role="button"` is deprecated in 1.4 and will be removed from 1.5, now classes are added manually.

```
<a href="#page" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-home">Anchor</a>
```

Moreover, jQM is now using SVG icons for platforms that support SVG and normal icons for ones that dont. Icons are added after an element using pseudo selector `:after`.

Creating custom icons is simple as the CSS below.

```
.ui-custom-icon:after {
  background-image: url('custom-icon.png');
  background-size: 25px 25px; /* dont forget this */
}
```

Now add `.ui-custom-icon` to any element.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Y3TUj/)**