# jQuery mobile, Custom buttons look different than standard icon buttons

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Using the following code I was able to get a custom icon on a jquery Mobile button. Somehow the button itself looks different than buttons that I use with standard jquery icons. The one with the custom icon looks pretty much flat whereas the other buttons have a somewhat "rounded" appearance. Is there something I'm missing that I have to do for them to look just as the others?

For each custom icon I have a 18x18px and a 36x36px version. The icons are transparent with a colored circle in the middle.

[image]

So here's the code:

```
.ui-icon-dreambox-blue {
        background-image: url("/static/images/dreambox-blue.png") !important;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
        background-position: center !important;
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
        .ui-icon-dreambox-blue {
        background-image: url("/static/images/dreambox-blue_highres.png") !important;
        background-size: 18px 18px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
        background-position: center !important;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="dreambox-blue" data-iconpos="notext">B</a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use `:after` pseudo selector to add your customs styles. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20861031/1771795

Comment: Are you using jQM 1.3? Are your buttons inside a controlgroup?

Comment: Thank you Omar, that did the trick. Not sure how to mark your answer as the actual answer to the question.