# can you override Jquery mobile stock icons in both white and black without html changes?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-themeroller

i want to override the default icons without needing custom HTML markup like data-icon. Basically, i should be able to just override the CSS of the default set.

I've tried this...

```
.ui-icon-delete:after {background-image:url("../img/assets/icon-close.svg");}
.ui-nosvg .ui-icon-delete:after {background-image: url("../img/assets/icon-close.png");}
```

But this does not work for icons in both color formats. I also do not want to override the actual images in theme-roller's icons-png and icons-svg folder.

What is the complete CSS for overriding all states of a default jquery mobile icon (with and without the disc background color)?

Comment: set `background-size` for example `background-size: 25px 25px;`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20861031/1771795

Comment: To color SVGs you usually use fill:

Comment: @Omar, that is already there from the original theme rolling and my icons are the same size

Comment: I apologize. I framed this question really poorly, but it did get an accurate answer given the title so i'll leave it. (For my issue, I thought my images were not showing up due to bad css inheritance, but turned out to be the SVG xml format as converted by ImageMagik. I re-saved those icons straight from Illustrator and they worked with black or white states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code replaces the white version of ui-icon-delete. To also replace the black version, use something like this:

```
.ui-alt-icon.ui-icon-delete:after,
.ui-alt-icon .ui-icon-delete:after {background-image:url("../img/assets/icon-close-black.svg");}
```